# How to extract white objects in an image(attached)? The program should then display each N as a separate figure.

Tags: template-matching

[image]

The program should take the given image as input and the end result should be each white object in a separate figure window.

Comment: Solving this problem has two aspects.  1) Knowing how to do the coding and 2) Having an algorithm.  is this a homework problem?  Which aspect are you really asking about?  Are your object's bounding rectangles ever going to overlap?

Comment: This question is far too broad as it is. Maybe you could post what you have tried so far and what are your problems with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about detecting intensities of pixels. It'll be better if you use MATLAB. Such binary images will have just 2 intensity levels 0(black) and 1(white).

No one is going to do it for you unless you are ready to pay. Buy and read a copy of Digital Image Processing by Gonzalez